# How to remove chapters from mkv metadata

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, metadata, mkv

How do you remove chapters from mkv metadata on command line? Can ffpmeg be used for this?

Comment: Don't know about FFMPEG. However, MKVToolNix (https://mkvtoolnix.download/docs.html) can be used. This program has a decent GUI and command-line options. A chapter Editor is also available in GUI. Read the documentation for command-line how tos.

Comment: Thanks! mkvpropedit movie.mkv --chapters '' did it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add -map_chapters -1 to your command.

```
Single Audio:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4
-map 0:0 -c copy
-map 0:1 -c copy
-map_chapters -1
output.mp4
```

```
Dual Audio with Subtitles:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4
-map 0:0 -c copy
-map 0:m:language:eng -c copy
-map 0:m:language:jpn -c copy
-map_chapters -1
output.mp4

Use ffmpeg -i video.mp4 to get the language identifiers
and change/add as many as you need to keep.
```

Comment: A bare command line is not really enough for a good answer on Ask Ubuntu. Could you add some details to your answer?

Comment: You are making too many assumptions. This also removes dual-audio and subtitles.

Comment: Edited answer, hopefully to your liking.